# Highcharts - not show due to change over the frequency time of one every second?

Tags: highcharts

Chart not show due to change over the frequency time of one every second. Display - shows a timeline display error start date more than end date & date overlapping.

reg = error , green&yellow = normal

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDkRq.jpg

Comment: is there a question?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b9ybypeq/

Comment: I have problems with the display of graphs. Because the timing is changed every 1 sec. @jlbriggs

Comment: http://codepen.io/patsawalai/pen/RaMYzQ

Comment: As mentioned by Aparna below, you are getting Highcharts error 17 - "series type does not exist". You are trying to use "columnrange", which requires the **highcharts-more,js** file to be included.

Comment: I made the corrections http://codepen.io/patsawalai/pen/RaMYzQ  
I have problems with the display of graphs. Because the timing is changed every 1 sec. @jlbriggs

Comment: Ok, you'll have to be more specific and ask an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, you are getting this error "Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17" which means that "The requested series type does not exist". Can you check your series data.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the [minPointLength](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.columnrange.minPointLength) parameter

```
plotOptions:{
   series:{
       minPointLength: 10
   }
}
```